# What are these 'Remote login' and 'File sharing' icons that I'm seeing under 'Networks'?

Tags: networking, nautilus, 22.04, network-monitoring

I'm new to Linux and currently running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I noticed recently in the drives section of my file manager(nautilus) that there are these two icons (image below) named 'Remote Login' and 'File sharing' under 'Networks'.
[image: screenshot 1]

When I click on the first icon that says 'Remote Login' I get this message (image below) in the dialogue box.
[image: screenshot 2]

Is my desktop's security compromised? Has someone gained access to my local machine? Should I be worried?

Comment: It looks like you have a device or computer in your home network with the IP address 192.168.0.2. Do you know what that device is? Please update you question with that information.

Comment: Does the device with IP address 192.168.0.2 have an user with same username as the Ubuntu computer where you see these icons?